# Does rebasing make it easier for the maintainer's integration work?

Tags: git

I am reading the git book from [Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). I have not gained any experience using git yet, so sorry if this question is premature.

I encountered the following quote about rebasing:
"Often, you’ll do this to make sure your commits apply cleanly on a remote branch — perhaps in a project to which you’re trying to contribute but that you don’t maintain. In this case, you’d do your work in a branch and then rebase your work onto origin/master when you were ready to submit your patches to the main project. That way, the maintainer doesn’t have to do any integration work — just a fast-forward or a clean apply."

Is the "integration work" fixing conflicts? My interpretation of the quote is that in rebasing, the contributor fixes the conflicts so that the maintainer does not have to. Is this correct? This implies that if you do not rebase, the maintainer is forced to fix the conflicts, but I do not see why this might be the case.

I skimmed the [next chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project), and see that the rebase workflow is as follows:

```
$ git checkout featureA
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git push -f myfork featureA
```

Somewhere you would have to fix the conflicts.

If the point is to prevent conflicts for the maintainer, you can still do so without rebasing:

```
$ git checkout featureA
$ git merge origin/master
$ git push myfork featureA
```

Here too, you would have to fix the conflicts.

In the context of the quote I do not see why "the maintainer doesn’t have to do any integration work" is an advantage only particular to rebasing.

Comment: Rebasing is like voting.  Do it early, do it often.

Comment: It’s just a matter of opinion. I prefer merges.